# Error in caffe installation

Tags: installation, caffe

I am facing a issue when i run the following command while installing caffe on fedora 21

```
make all
```

Output:

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libleveldb.so when searching for -lleveldb
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libleveldb.so when searching for -lleveldb
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../libleveldb.so when searching for -lleveldb
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libleveldb.so when searching for -lleveldb
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libleveldb.so when searching for -lleveldb
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lleveldb
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsnappy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:544: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
[root@parags-pc caffe]#
```

Some help please!

I still can't get rid of the last two (-lcblas and -latlas) errors. I have installed atlas and OpenBLAS long ago. Also I tried the following commands but with no success

```
echo "/usr/lib64/atlas" >/etc/ld.so.conf.d/atlas-x86_64.conf
ldconfig -v
```

Need some inputs!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leveldb present in your system seems to be of a different architecture, most probably a 32bit compiled leveldb and 64bit compiled caffe, or vice-versa.

The rest of the libraries are to be installed in Fedora before compiling Caffe.

Comment: Yes you were right. I had installed 32bit leveldb instead of a 64bit version. Now that problem has gone. Also problem related to snappy was resolved after I installled snappy using 'yum install snappy-devel'.